# How to create a el-table-tree structure with dynamic json data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, vuejs2, treetable

I have a task in which I need to convert an Array of Objects data to specified data tree structure for to display it in frontend `tree-table`. This below is my Array of Objects data.

```
<!-- This is my JSON Data -->
Collection: {
  Fields: [{
      fieldName: 'mainField',
      properties: [{
          id: 1,
          carName: 'carName_01',
          type:string'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          carName: 'carName_02',
          type: 'object',
          ref: 'subField'
        }]
    },
    {
      fieldName: 'subField',
      properties: [{
          id: 1,
          carName: 'carName_11',
          type: 'string'
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          carName: 'carName_12',
          type: 'object',
          ref: 'subField1'
        }]
    },
    {
      fieldName: 'subField1',
      properties: [{
          id: 1,
          carName: 'carName_21',
          type: 'string'
        }]
    }]
}
```

I have to change this data into this below following data structure.

```
<!-- Desired Output -->
tableData: [{
          id: 1,
          carName: 'carName_01',
          type: 'string'
        },
  {
    id: 2,
    carName: 'carName_02',
    type: 'object'
    source: 'subField'
    children: [{
      id: 11,
      carName: 'carName_11',
      type: 'object',
      ref: 'subField1',
      children: [{
      id: 12,
      carName: 'carName_12',
      type: 'string'
      }]
    }
```

I have tried to do this using Recursion in methods but, I can't do that in a way that I want. My task is I have to add an children whenever the `type: 'object'` is object with another referenced object inside that array of objects. And by the way the data is dyanmic which is from mongodb database. That's just a simplified version of the code.
If my information is not enough or seemed unreasonable sorry for that, I am fresher so, I just asked what i want. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First

First, two notes:

- On StackOverflow, we expect you to do your own work, and to present your best attempt, explaining where it went wrong.  This is a question-and-answer site, not a code-it-for-you one.  I'm going to try to answer you this time, but for the future, please read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).
- Your comment "This is my JSON Data" is not accurate.  JSON is a string format, used to transfer data between different systems or store it.  What you have here is plain JavaScript data structures.

### Answer

I think this is a fairly simple solution.  But it makes one assumption that may not be justified.  I didn't see any way to distinguish your root objects in your input structure, except that they were first.  I chose to use the first `model` as the source of your root objects.  If you need to choose instead the one that has the model name of `"form"`, we could change that easily enough.

The code looks like this:

```js
const convertModels = (models, key) => 
  models .filter (({model}) => model == key) .flatMap (
    ({attributes}) => attributes .map (att => ({
      ... att,
      ... (att.type == 'object' ? {children: convertModels (models, att.source)} : {})
    }))
  )

const convert = (dictionary) => ({
  tableData: convertModels (dictionary .models, dictionary .models [0] .model)
})

const dictionary = {models: [{model: "form", attributes: [{id: 1, name: "field_01", displayName: "Field 01", type: "string"}, {id: 2, name: "field_02", displayName: "Field 02", type: "object", source: "subForm"}]}, {model: "subForm", attributes: [{id: 11, name: "subForm_01", displayName: "Field 01", type: "string"}, {id: 12, name: "subForm_02", displayName: "Field 02", type: "object", source: "dialogForm"}]}, {model: "dialogForm", attributes: [{id: 21, name: "dialogForm_01", displayName: "Field 01", type: "string"}]}]}

console .log (convert (dictionary))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Our main function is `convertModels`, which accepts a list of models and the key we're going to search for.  It searches the models for those one(s) with that key, and then flat-maps their `attributes` by copying all properties and, if the type is `"object"`, adding a `children` node by recurring on the models and the `source` field.

We wrap this in `convert` which handles your outer object, its `models` property `convert` along with the first model's `model` property, storing the result in a `tableData` property of a new object.

---

If you did want to use the `"form"` identifier instead of using the first record, the code is slightly simpler:

```js
const convertModels = (models, key = 'form') =>   // only slightly more complex
  models .filter (({model}) => model == key) .flatMap (
    ({attributes}) => attributes .map (att => ({
      ... att,
      ... (att.type == 'object' ? {children: convertModels (models, att.source)} : {})
    }))
  )

const convert = (dictionary) => ({
  tableData: convertModels (dictionary .models)  // simpler
})
```

Comment: I am very sorry for that, I am a fresher who entered the software field recently and it my fault to asking something like this. I will change that and never do that in the fututre and thanks for your reply. It helped me a lot...